# Is it possible to curry generic functions in Dart?

Tags: dart

Let's assume I have a generic function that creates list.

```
List<T> createList<T>() => <T>[];
```

Can I curry `T` in `createList`? The following does not compile:

```
final createIntList = createList<int>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess you can't exactly, but try wrapping it in another function like this:

```
final creareIntList = () => createList<int>();
```

I know it's not as pretty but it's still a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* partially apply the type argument, but you there is no *syntax* for it. It's one of the few things in Dart which can *only* be done using type inference.

If you write:

```dart
List<int> Function() createIntList = createList;
```

then type inference will make this a tear-off equivalent to:

```dart
List<int> Function() createIntList = () => createList<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be released with Dart v2.15 but can be enabled as an experiment in your `analysis_options.yaml` file:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - constructor-tearoffs
```